# Why does my MVC4 project not have debug and release folders under the bin folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I build my app, I just get a single `bin` folder, with all files in it, versus the usual `bin\debug` and `bin\release` folders. Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the website can be run by IIS ( and the various flavours of... ) in the location you built.

IIS expects the assemblies in the bin folder ( it's hard wired in the AppDomain setup ) so the web project type compile to this location.

Answer (score 2):

For an interview, i was put across with this question. [One of the link could be this which answers in brief](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DebugRelease.aspx) .

The [above](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DebugRelease.aspx) link will give you the statement as below:-

**Release Mode**

> When an assembly is built in release mode, the compiler performs all
>   available optimisations to ensure that the outputted executables and
>   libraries execute as efficiently as possible. This mode should be used
>   for completed and tested software that is to be released to end-users.
>   The drawback of release mode is that whilst the generated code is
>   usually faster and smaller, it is not accessible to debugging tools.

**Debug Mode**

> Debug mode is used whilst developing software. When an assembly is
>   compiled in debug mode, additional symbolic information is embedded
>   and the code is not optimised. This means that the output of the
>   compiler is generally larger, slower and less efficient. However, a
>   debugger can be attached to the running program to allow the code to
>   be stepped through whilst monitoring the values of internal variables.

[Update] After little google i came across [similar question- "Confused about Release/Debug folders in Visual Studio 2010"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517383/confused-about-release-debug-folders-in-visual-studio-2010) with same answer which i have quoted above.

Also, please look into [why-have-separate-debug-and-release-folders-in-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049844/why-have-separate-debug-and-release-folders-in-visual-studio). `@riko` and other members of Stackoverflow have answered quiet well..

Comment: I'm not asking why we have separate release and debug folders; I'm asking why the MVC4 project **doesn't** have separate release and debug folders.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is not specific to MVC4. In fact it is consistent with so-called "classic" ASP.Net, both Web Site projects and Web Applications.

The distinction between release and debug modes in ASP.Net is that Release builds need to be Published.

Comment: not correct, you can build using the release build config and run it exactly the same way.